# How to show struts2 tags in javascript as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am using struts2 tags and want to create a `<tr></tr>` dynamically to add a new row in a table.
Problem is that inside `""` struts2 tags are not treated as simple string.

```
 function add_table_row() {   
     var t = $('#item-table .row:last').attr('id');
     var num = t.substring(4);
     var num1 = parseInt(num) + 1;
 $("#item-table .row:last").after(" <tr class=\"row\" id=\"item" + num1 + "\">"
        + "<td><s:textfield name="billProductList[0].productDetails.barcode" value="%{billProductList[0].productDetails.barcode}" cssClass="barcode" cssStyle="width:50px"/></td>"
        + "<td><s:textfield name="billProductList[0].productDetails.productTypes.productType" value="%{billProductList[0].productDetails.productTypes.productType}" cssClass="productType" cssStyle="width:250px"/>");
};
```

How to resolve this. 
How can I use struts2 tags as simple string in jsp page.

Comment: Can you include your markup ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov I didnt get you. What extra should i post

Comment: @xrcwrn: What do you mean by *struts2 tags are not treated as simple string.*?

Comment: It is not working.when putting inside `""`

Comment: @AleksandrM Is it correct way to add struts2 tags in `""`

Comment: Is your `add_table_row` function in separate js file? This won't work because S2 tags won't be evaluated.